# how to fix duplicate asset path in laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

when i load the page there's no error at all in the console. but then, when i saw the url of the css and javascript. it got asset path appended twice e.g

```
<link href="http://localhost:8080/css/all.css/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://localhost:8080/css/all.css/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://localhost:8080/css/all.css/js/app.js" type="text/javascipt" defer></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/css/all.css/js/script.js" type="text/javascipt" defer></script>
```

my .env file APP_URL is defined as http://localhost:8080

I linked the assets like this in my code

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/all.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascipt" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}" type="text/javascipt" defer></script>
```

what's wrong with it ?

my js files are inside /public/assets/js 
while my css files are inside /public/assets/css

is there anything that i should do to fix this duplicate path? because the css and js does not reflect at all

my webpack is like this

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/assets/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/assets/css');

mix.js('resources/js/script.js','public/assets/js');

mix.styles(['resources/css/main.css'],'public/assets/css/all.css');
```

Comment: remove your assets  in your webpack, it should be public/js not public/assets/js

Comment: even if I remove it, the duplicate is still there...the laravel documentation says, we need to define the ASSET_URL in the .env , whenever we use the asset() helper function ..that's why I tried to put public/assets ...initially i don't have an assets folder and I'm already seeing that duplicate path ...i only use the assets folder to follow the documentation and yet still the issue occurs

Comment: I already removed the assets folder and and made it public/js , and public/css...then I alreday removed the assets from the webpack...I rebuild...same issue occurs

Comment: what are errors occured ?

Comment: there's no error, but am seeing this same stuff

Comment: `<link href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/css/all.css/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/css/all.css/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/css/all.css/js/app.js" type="text/javascipt" defer></script>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/css/all.css/js/script.js" type="text/javascipt" defer></script>`

Comment: did you removed already your assets folder in your public ?

Comment: yes i did removed already...its now public/js , public/css

Comment: restart laravel, clear chache, routes

Comment: same `<link href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/css/all.css/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/css/all.css/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/css/all.css/js/app.js" type="text/javascipt" defer></script>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/css/all.css/js/script.js" type="text/javascipt" defer></script>`

Comment: show the url returned by asset(), it seems your asset() includes an assets dir

Comment: my problem solved. i was running laravel wrong way. php -S 127.0.0.1:8080 -t public public/index.php ....then i tried php artisan serve ...the css reflected

Answer (score 0):

So for laravel 6. here's how i solved my own issue. it seems like there's no need for the web pack for me, so in my application i placed all the js and css inside the public directory and included them like this in the code

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/all.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascipt"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>   


<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}"></script>
```

everything worked